# Pentaho Kettle - batch script doesn't produce output

Tags: batch-file, jobs, pentaho, kettle

I've written a very simple pentaho kettle script that works fine when I launch it from the spoon ide. It takes in a csv file and writes it to a text file and an xml file. However, if I run it as a batch job using pan.bat, it doesn't create or update either of the files it's supposed to. I'm running it as xml (not through the repository)

Here's the command:

```
C:\test\data-integration>pan.bat /file ./demo/hello.ktr /level:Basic
```

Here is this output:

```
INFO  24-11 13:18:43,765 - Using "C:\DOCUME~1\mcd\LOCALS~1\Temp\vfs_cache" as te
mporary files store.
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,156 - Pan - Pan
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,156 - Pan - Pan
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,312 - hello - Dispatching started for transformation [hello
]
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,343 - hello - This transformation can be replayed with repl
ay date: 2010/11/24 13:18:44
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,343 - File with Greetings - Opening output stream in encodi
ng: UTF-8
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,375 - CSV file input - Header row skipped in file 'file:///
C:/test/data-integration/demo/list.csv'
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,375 - CSV file input - Finished processing (I=7, O=0, R=0,
W=6, U=0, E=0)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - Greetings - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=6, W=12,
 U=0, E=0)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - File with Greetings - Finished processing (I=0, O=6,
R=6, W=6, U=0, E=0)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - Text file output - Finished processing (I=0, O=7, R=6
, W=6, U=0, E=0)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - Pan - Pan
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - Pan - Pan
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,593 - Pan - Pan
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,609 - hello -
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,609 - hello - Step CSV file input.0 ended successfully, processed 6 lines. ( - lines/s)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,609 - hello - Step Greetings.0 ended successfully, processe
d 12 lines. ( - lines/s)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,609 - hello - Step File with Greetings.0 ended successfully
, processed 6 lines. ( - lines/s)
INFO  24-11 13:18:44,609 - hello - Step Text file output.0 ended successfully, p
rocessed 6 lines. ( - lines/s)
```

This should create/update a couple of files, but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved -  the output was pointed to a different directory than I thought. I definitely had corrected that, but I must have input the change to the original file as opposed to the one I was working with. Never make copies unless you need to.

Comment: +1 For answering your own question, and owning up to your mistake. "A copy is not a copy unless it's a copy, but then if it's a copy, is it really a copy... :-)